# Can't delete file even as root

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, files, delete, rm

I tried to delete a directory by running `sudo rm -rf google-chrome`. This gave no output message but the directory wasn't deleted. There is only one file remaining, google-chrome/default/User\ StyleSheets/Custom.css.

I tried to `cd` to the User\ Stylesheets directory and remove the file but that didn't work.

I ran `sudo rm Custom.css`, but the file wasn't deleted (and no output from `rm`).

How can I delete it?

More info:
`ls -la Custom.css` gives

```
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 0 Oct 21 02:42 Custom.css
```

`lsattr Custom.css` gives

```
    -------------e- Custom.css
```

(the immutable bit is not set)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely some process is holding the file open and/or immediately recreating it when you delete it. Try the following command:

```
sudo lsof google-chrome/default/User\ StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

This should tell you what program is locking the file. You may then kill it, and (hopefully) delete the file. Failing that, a reboot should fix it good.

Comment: I got this output from `lsof`: 

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/david/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.

Comment: Rebooting seems to have solved it though. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, root can't look into your gvfs, so try without sudo. However, since the file wasn't in that folder, it probably wouldn't have worked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I often have the same problem using chromium on Debian Testing. The Custom.css file was indeed blocked by a running program but `lsof` wouldn't let me know of it. So I just made a:

```
ps -aux | grep chromium
```

Which gave me the list of all running chromium instances, and there were 3 or 4! After killing them all I could just remove the Custom.css file without a problem.